# Converting Downloaded Video Lecture (.dthf format) to mp4

Tags: file, mp4

### Subject: Help Needed: Converting Downloaded Video Lecture (.dthf format) to mp4

Hi everyone,

I'm hoping to get some help with a video lecture file I downloaded for studies. The file format is .dthf, and I'm struggling to find a way to convert it to mp4 because I am unable to run/play it.

**Here's what I know:**

- I downloaded the video lecture from within an application/software program of a coaching company.
- - The downloaded file format is .dthf.

**What I'm trying to achieve:**

- Convert the .dthf file to a more common format like mp4 for easier playback cause I am unable to run/play it.

**What I've tried so far:**

- I've searched online for converters that support .dthf files, but haven't found much success.

**I'm hoping the community can help with:**

- **Software recommendations:** Are there any specific software programs (free or paid) that might be able to convert .dthf files to mp4?
- **Online converters (with caution):** While I'm cautious about online converters, are there any reputable services known to work with .dthf formats?
- **Information about the source application:** Does anyone have experience with applications that might use .dthf for video lectures? Any insights on how to play or convert these files within the original software would be appreciated.

Any suggestions or information from the community would be a huge help! Thanks in advance for your time and assistance.

Thank you once again.

Here's what I know:**

- I downloaded the video lecture from within an application/software program of a coaching company.
- - The downloaded file format is .dthf.

**What I'm trying to achieve:**

- Convert the .dthf file to a more common format like mp4 for easier playback cause I am unable to run/play it.

**What I've tried so far:**

- I've searched online for converters that support .dthf files, but haven't found much success.

**I'm hoping the community can help with:**

- **Software recommendations:** Are there any specific software programs (free or paid) that might be able to convert .dthf files to mp4?
- **Online converters (with caution):** While I'm cautious about online converters, are there any reputable services known to work with .dthf formats?
- **Information about the source application:** Does anyone have experience with applications that might use .dthf for video lectures? Any insights on how to play or convert these files within the original software would be appreciated

Comment: Your best bet is `FFMpeg`. You can try to run this in command line `ffmpeg.exe -i "lecture.dthf" -vn -y -ar 44100 -b:a 192000 -fflags +bitexact -f mp4 "output"`. You can create script doing this automatically almost in any programming language.

Comment: Thank so much for the answer.... I tried what you said but I am unable to do it....I can send you the file and can you help me with that ...it will be a great help for me as it is so much important for me right now. Thank you again

Comment: @PleaseReply _"Here's what I know..."_ and then proceeds to be mysterious. What lecture file? What software/app? What coaching company? You told us nothing useful... Tell us what app you know that plays these `.dthf` files? If it is a custom file format (that only works in their player )then it's not possible for you to convert into MP4. Maybe just **screen record** if you're desperate to pirate someone else's hard work. PS: Do you think `.dthf` stands for **deter thief** (_eg:_ this is a secure/encrypted format that is not playable by other software)?.